# Taylor remainder in integral form

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, power-series, taylor-expansion

> Let f be infinitely differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ and let
>   $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> We can write the function $f(x)$ as
>
> $$f(x)=f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x{f'(t)dt}$$  or
>   $$f(x)=f(x_0)-\int_{x_0}^x{f'(t)d(x-t)}$$
>
> With partial integration we get
>
> $$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)-\int_{x_0}^{x}{f''(t)\cdot t \ dt}$$
>
> And with induction it can be proved that
>
> $$f(x)=f(x_0)+\frac{f'(x_0)}{1!}(x-x_0)+\cdots
>  +\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n+R_{n+1}$$ where $$R_{n+1}=-\frac{1}{n!}\cdot \int_{x_0}^x{f^{(n+1)}(t)\cdot t^ndt}$$

The first line is pretty clear to me. However I fail to see how the second equality is equivalent to the first. This $d(x-t)$ confuses me a lot. I also know that we choose $f'(t)=u$ so $f''(t)dt=du$ however not sure what we are choosing as $dv$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $dv$ is chosen to be $d(x-t)$, that is, $v=x-t$.

Comment: $d(x-t)= -dt$ (because $x$ is constant with respect to integration), hence the minus sign in the second equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in the second and third equations, so it is understandable how you are confused.

Here is what is going on starting from the first equation $$f(x)=f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x{f'(t)dt}.$$ We integrate by parts using $u=f'(t)$ and $v=x-t$, so $dv=-dt$.  We thus have 
\begin{align*}
\int_{x_0}^x{f'(t)dt} &=-\int_{x_0}^x f'(t)(-dt) \\
&=-(f'(t)(x-t))\Big|_{x_0}^x+\int_{x_0}^xf''(t)(x-t)dt \\
&=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\int_{x_0}^xf''(t)(x-t)dt.
\end{align*}
Plugging this back into the first equation we have $$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\int_{x_0}^xf''(x)(x-t)dt.$$ This is almost what the (erroneous) third equation says, but with $x-t$ instead of $-t$ in the integrand.

(Looking back on this, you can see the second equation as an attempt to rewrite the integral in the form $\int udv$ with $u=f'(t)$ and $v=x-t$.  However, it is incorrect, since if you rewrite the integral with $d(x-t)$, you must also change the bounds of integration to be in terms of $x-t$ instead of in terms of $t$.)